# Express not catching exception in middleware

Tags: node.js, express

I'm attempting to use middleware to catch exceptions in routes.

**Expected Result:**

When an error is thrown in a route I expect it to be caught by the middleware so I can log the error and return a generic response.

**Actual Result:**

When an error is thrown in the route the middleware is never reached. An Error and stacktrace is printed to the console and the browser displays `Internal Server Error`. The except thrown:

```
> NODE_ENV=production node api/server.js

Listening on port 8080!
Error: Error in /invite route
    at app.get (/Users/bughunter/Projects/ooberoo/lander/api/server.js:42:8)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/bughunter/Projects/ooberoo/lander/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/Users/bughunter/Projects/ooberoo/lander/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/Users/bughunter/Projects/ooberoo/lander/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/bughunter/Projects/ooberoo/lander/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /Users/bughunter/Projects/ooberoo/lander/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (/Users/bughunter/Projects/ooberoo/lander/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/Users/bughunter/Projects/ooberoo/lander/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/bughunter/Projects/ooberoo/lander/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:91:12)
```

Application is ran from npm `start` script:

```
"start": "NODE_ENV=production node api/server.js",
```

My code is below:

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const winston = require('winston');
require('winston-daily-rotate-file');

// Are we production or development?
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';

// Express
const app = express();

// Logger
const logger = new (winston.Logger)({
  transports: [ 
    new (winston.transports.DailyRotateFile)({
      filename: path.resolve(__dirname, '../logs/app.log'),
      datePattern: 'yyyy-MM-dd.',
      prepend: true,
      level: process.env.ENV === 'development' ? 'debug' : 'info'
    })
   ]
});

// Static files
app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, 'static')));

// Generic error middleware
app.use(function(error, req, res, next) {
  logger.log('error', error);
  res.status(500);
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  res.json({ error: 'Failed to process request' });
});

// Homepage
app.get('/', (req, res) =>
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, './static/index.html'))
);

// Invite signup
app.get('/invite', (req, res, next) => {
  next(new Error('Error in /invite route'));
});

// Redirect to home if no route found
app.get('*', (req, res) =>
  res.redirect('/')
);

app.listen(8080, () =>
  console.log('Listening on port 8080!')
);
```

I'm doing what it says in the [documentation](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html) yet it doesn't appear to work. Any advice here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Error middleware must be declared in the last, after all other middleware and routes:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => ...

app.get('/invite', (req, res, next) => ...

app.get('*', (req, res) => ...

app.use((error, req, res, next) => { ... // <= declare error middleware here
```

Comment: I can not believe I wasted so much time on such a simple issue! Works now.

Comment: I thought the middleware method arguments can only be `function(req,res,next)` i've never seen an `error` argument from the [docs](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#middleware-callback-function-examples)

Comment: @BugHunterUK, Middleware functions are executed sequentially, therefore the order of middleware inclusion is important.